# PowerShell script to connect to multiple accounts

Tags: powershell

I need to run a script on multiple office365 accounts, so I Have the usernames (Emails) in a file and the password in another file (Same password for all). but I get this error message, and I don't have 2FA enables on the accounts.

Connect-MsolService : Authentication Error: Unable to complete authentication request (potentially a proxy issue)

That's the whole script:

```
    $passwordFile = "C:\password.txt"
$username = "C:\users.txt"

# First time create password file
if (! (Test-Path $passwordFile))
{
  Read-Host -AsSecureString | convertfrom-securestring | out-file $passwordFile
}
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $passwordFile -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

$licensedUsers = Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential

$licensedUsers  = Get-MsolUser -All | ? { $_.UserType -ne "Guest" }

$Report = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new() # Create output file
Write-Host "Processing" $licensedUsers.Count "accounts..." 
ForEach ($User in $licensedUsers) {
    $MFAEnforced = $User.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State
    $MFAPhone = $User.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.PhoneNumber
    $DefaultMFAMethod = ($User.StrongAuthenticationMethods | ? { $_.IsDefault -eq "True" }).MethodType
    If (($MFAEnforced -eq "Enforced") -or ($MFAEnforced -eq "Enabled")) {
        Switch ($DefaultMFAMethod) {
            "OneWaySMS" { $MethodUsed = "One-way SMS" }
            "TwoWayVoiceMobile" { $MethodUsed = "Phone call verification" }
            "PhoneAppOTP" { $MethodUsed = "Hardware token or authenticator app" }
            "PhoneAppNotification" { $MethodUsed = "Authenticator app" }
        }
    }
    Else {
        $MFAEnforced = "Not Enabled"
        $MethodUsed = "MFA Not Used" 
    }
  
    $ReportLine = [PSCustomObject] @{
        User        = $User.UserPrincipalName
        Name        = $User.DisplayName
        MFAUsed     = $MFAEnforced
        MFAMethod   = $MethodUsed 
        PhoneNumber = $MFAPhone
    }
                 
    $Report.Add($ReportLine) 
}

Write-Host "Report is in c:\temp\MFAUsers.CSV"
$Report | Select User, Name, MFAUsed, MFAMethod, PhoneNumber | Sort Name | Out-GridView
$Report | Sort Name | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 c:\temp\MFAUsers.csv
```

Comment: Your giving the password file to the convert command, you need to get the password contents

Answer (score 0):

You need to "read" the password from the file.
Here is an example.

```
$password = Get-Content $passwordFile| ConvertTo-SecureString
```

Comment: Hi,  

I have modified the first part to this:

$Secure = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$Encrypted = ConvertFrom-SecureString -SecureString $Secure -Key (1..16)
$Encrypted | Set-Content Encrypted.txt
$Secure2 = Get-Content Encrypted.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (1..16)
$username = "C:\script\user.txt"


$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $Secure2

now i get this error: Connect-MsolService : Authentication Error: Unable to complete authentication request (potentially a proxy issue)

Comment: I managed to fix the logging in issue,  but now how do loop through the users in the txt file?

Comment: What do you want to do with the users in the loop?